# Programmatically logout from Facebook and change FB login auth button state android

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using FB login auth button for FB login in my android app.
It's working fine.

Now in some other activity, I need to logout from app and thus from FB, and change FB login button state.
I've tried this:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

This doesn't work.
Please help.

Comment: use this [function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27183810/1535314) and clear your preferences if exists

Comment: already tried. didn't work.